# Case studies for .NET

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone please share if you have any case studies to get practice on user controls, caching , linq, multithreading, remoting concepts in ASP.NET?

or kindly refer any of the website to get the above information

Comment: Welcome To SO! Kindly review your question and before asking any please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thank you

Comment: I think you should search for individual technology and start learning, as a start you can use ContosoUniveristy